# Opentype fonts in OpenOffice

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, openoffice, opentype

How to get opentype fonts in .otf format working on Ubuntu and OpenOffice 3.2?

It would be great if I could use opentype features in OOo, but I'll be glad enough if I could use them even converted to TTF.

I've tried numerous ways described on the net, but with no success. For now, I succeeded with using OTF fonts in Inkscape.

- How to get it working with OOo?
- Any news about opentype in upcoming versions of OOo?
- Can you recommend any other alternative to MS Word, or better yet Adobe Indesign with good OTF support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenType fonts should work with OpenOffice.org 3.2 (unless there is a bug somewhere in either the font or OOo).

An alternative to InDesign could be [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net) (also available in the Ubuntu repositories).

Answer (score 1):

In at least since jaunty, I've never even thought about font support, it just works. I think the magic is contained in the [fontconfig](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/fontconfig) package.

For a good time, try:

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
```

Comment: Did you mean `sudo apt-get install fontconfig`? This does not help at all. Fonts are working, but not i OOo.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the syntax error, fixed. I am using Ubuntu Lucid OO 3.2 and have fonts that are shown by `fc-list`, have never been released as anything other than OTF, only live on my machine as OTF and they work fine. I do not know what I'm doing differently, sorry.